# Python multiprocess debugging

Tags: python, debugging, multiprocessing, pycharm, winpdb

I'm trying to debug a simple python application but no luck so far.

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(num):
    for a in range(0, 10):
        print a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
```

I want to set a breakpoint inside the for-loop to track the values of 'a' but non of the tools that I tried are able to do that.
So far I tried debuging with:

- PyCharm and get the following error: ImportError: No module named
  pydevd - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6649 It looks like
  they are still working on a fix for this and from what I understand, no ETA on this
- I also tried debuging with Winpdb - http://winpdb.org but it simply won't go inside my 'worker' method and just print the values of 'a'

I would really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: When it comes to multiprocessing/multithreading, there's no such thing as "simple". In my opinion, at least.

Comment: That is Windows-specific bug in PyCharm debugger.If you really need to debug application using multiprocessing module, I can recommend to use Unix virtual machine and setup remote interpreter to that VM from your PyCharm.

Answer (score 8):

I found it very useful to replace `multiprocessing.Process()` with `threading.Thread()` when I'm going to set breakpoints. Both classes have similar arguments so in most cases they are interchangeable.

Usually my scripts use `Process()` until I specify command line argument `--debug` which effectively replaces those calls with `Thread()`. That allows me to debug those scripts with `pdb`.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do it with `remote-pdb`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def test(thing):
  from remote_pdb import set_trace
  set_trace()
  s = thing*2
  print(s)
  return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Pool(5) as p:
    print(p.map(test,['dog','cat','bird']))
```

Then just `telnet` to the port that's listed in the log.

Example:

```
RemotePdb session open at 127.0.0.1:54273, waiting for connection ...
```

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 54273
<telnet junk>
-> s = thing*2
(Pdb)
```

or

```
nc -tC 127.0.0.1 54273

-> s = thing * 2
(Pdb)
```

You should be able to debug the process at that point.

Answer (score 2):

I copied everything in `/Applications/PyCharm\ 2.6\ EAP.app/helpers/pydev/*.py` to `site-packages` in my virtualenv and it worked for my (I'm debugging celery/kombu, breakpoints work as expected).

Answer (score 2):

It would be great if regular pdb/ipdb would work with multiprocessing. If I can get away with it, I handle calls to multiprocessing serially if the number of configured processes is 1.

```
if processes == 1:
    for record in data:
        worker_function(data)
else:
    pool.map(worker_function, data)
```

Then when debugging, configure the application to only use a single process. This doesn't cover all cases, especially when dealing with concurrency issues, but it might help.

Answer (score 1):

I've rarely needed to use a traditional debugger when attempting to debug Python code, preferring instead to liberally sprinkle my code with trace statements. I'd change your code to the following:

```
import multiprocessing
import logging

def worker(num):
    for a in range(0, 10):
        logging.debug("(%d, %d)" % (num, a))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        logging.info("Starting process %d" % i)
        p.start()
```

In production, you disable the debug trace statements by setting the trace level to logging.WARNING so you only log warnings and errors.

There's a good [basic](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) and [advanced](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial) logging tutorial on the official Python site.

Comment: I truly appreciate your quick response but unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. What I should have mentioned in my question, is that this is just a simple example of the functionality that I need but in reality I'm dealing with complex objects and I need breakpoints to see their content at a certain time. Simple printing the content would not be enough.

Comment: I don't know of any python debugger that is as capable as the Visual Studio debugger. Perhaps you could modify the logging technique to only log under certain conditions, effectively simulating a conditional breakpoint?

Comment: logging is great, but it isn't free even when the logging level is set above the logging statement level since function calls have a significant cost in a dynamic language like Python.  It's good to know a debugger, and pdb ships with Python. Then it's just a problem of setting your multiprocessing project up correctly.

Comment: In some instances, you have to force trace statements to be printed because of buffering.

Comment: @Nielsvh how do I do that?

Comment: @cymruu See https://stackoverflow.com/a/230774/892327 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/230780/892327. Buffering is usually good for performance, so disabling it is probably not the best idea.

Comment: I've experienced the process hanging during logging resulting from using loggers like this with multiprocessing. It regularly worked Perhaps this is more related to the `RotatingFileHandler` than the logger

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to debug multiple processes running simultaneously, as shown in your example, then there's no obvious way to do that from a single terminal: which process should get the keyboard input? Because of this, Python [always connects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) `sys.stdin` in the child process to `os.devnull`. But this means that when the debugger tries to get input from stdin, it immediately reaches end-of-file and reports an error.

If you can limit yourself to one subprocess at a time, at least for debugging, then you could get around this by setting `sys.stdin = open(0)` to reopen the main stdin, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74225357/3830997).

But if multiple subprocesses may be at breakpoints simultaneously, then you will need a different solution, since they would all end up fighting over input from the single terminal. In that case, `RemotePdb` is probably your best bet, as described by @OnionKnight.

Answer (score -1):

[WingIDE Pro](https://wingware.com/) provides this functionality right out-of-the-box.

No additional code (e.g., use of the `traceback` module) is needed. You just run your program, and the Wing debugger will not only print `stdout` from subprocesses, but it will break on errors in a subprocess and **instantly create and an interactive shell so you can debug the offending thread**. It doesn't get any easier than this, and I know of no other IDE that exposes subprocesses in this way.

Yes, it's a commercial product. But I have yet to find any other IDE that provides a debugger to match. PyCharm Professional, Visual Studio Community, Komodo IDE - I've tried them all. WingIDE also leads in parsing source documentation as well, in my opinion. And the Eye Ease Green color scheme is something I can't live without now.

(Yes, I realize this question is 5+ years old. I'm answering it anyway.)