# How to use ipdb.set_trace in a forked process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipython, pdb, ipdb

I use `ipdb.set_trace()` whenever I need to set a break point in my code. Right now, I'm trying to use it in a process that I've created using `multiprocessing`, while the code does stop, I can't type anything to continue debugging. Is there any way to get my `stdin` directed properly?

Ideally, I would like to imagine a new console opening everytime a forked process is stopped for debugging, however I don't think this is possible.

Comment: It would be nice if you verify the answer given by @yoav-glazner. Are you able to use your keyboard after changing _multiprocessing_ by _dummy_?.

Comment: @jgomo3 I have confirmed it does work, but I (personally) don't feel it answers my question

Comment: I suppose for the fact that you had to change te code every time you want to debug. One could argue you do it already with pdb.set_trace(), but I know you fell there should be another way to achieve the same without changing the code.

I wonder if is there a way to tell pdb to use dummy instead of multiprocessing for the multiprocessing import? A kind of monkeypatching/mocking for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [How to attach debugger to a python subproccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716533/how-to-attach-debugger-to-a-python-subproccess), http://winpdb.org supports `multiprocessing` debugging.

If you'd prefer doing more work for more flexibility, there are some interesting ideas at https://gist.github.com/csabahenk/6497709 (too long to include here).

Comment: Did you try WinPDB on a python3 application? It seems to me that it's useful only to debug python2 programs

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes for debugging You can change your code to use **multiprocessing.dummy** . This way, no fork will be done, it will work with threads and be easier to debug.

Later on (after the bug is squashed...) you can switch back to **multiprocessing**

multiprocessing.dummy - should offer the same API as multiprocessing so its an easy change...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `pdb.set_trace()` use the following:

```
import sys
import pdb

class ForkedPdb(pdb.Pdb):
    """A Pdb subclass that may be used
    from a forked multiprocessing child

    """
    def interaction(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _stdin = sys.stdin
        try:
            sys.stdin = open('/dev/stdin')
            pdb.Pdb.interaction(self, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            sys.stdin = _stdin

ForkedPdb().set_trace()
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23654936/3450064