# Correct Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to track a user's decision before a certain time - and to do this, I am asking for input, while setting a timer. I am trying to use these two concurrently, so that the timer will go while there is a query for input. My solution at the moment is not working - could someone please tell me what I need to do to succeed here?

```
# pft4.py

from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def attack_request():
    attack_query = input("Do you want to attack? ")
    print(attack_query)

def attack_timer():
    timer = 0
    for i in range(3): 
        timer += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Timer updated: " + str(timer))
    return timer

def main():
    process_1 = Process(target = attack_request)
    process_2 = Process(target = attack_timer)
    process_1.run(); process_2.run()
    process_1.join(); process_2.join()
    # attack_request()
    # attack_timer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: use threading instead of multiprocessing

Comment: you need concurrency not parallelism

Comment: you don't even need a timer. just store the start time of the timer and do a subtraction.

Comment: See [How to set time limit on raw_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-raw-input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `Process.start()`, not `Process.run()`. `run()` just executes the process's main function. It does *not* arrange for this function to be run in a different process. `start()` does exactly that. See the reference documentation of the `Process` class.

In your code, `process_1.run()` will execute `attack_request()` and block until that returns. Then it does the same with `attack_timer()`. If you use `start()` instead then both will be executed simultaneously.

See also this related post: [Python multiprocessing stdin input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134297/python-multiprocessing-stdin-input/30149635)
Getting input from `stdin` may not be simple. Probably better to use threading, like others suggested.