# How can I profile a Rails app in its entirety, not just controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, profiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tools do you recommend to profile Rails apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350470/what-tools-do-you-recommend-to-profile-rails-apps)

My rails app is taking ~2 seconds to respond to POST requests, and I can't figure out why. When I use traditional profiling tools like newrelic or things that hook into unit tests, they tell me that all of my requests are fast, taking under 20 ms. But when I actually time the requests, they are taking 2 seconds. GET requests are fast. This happens in both development and production mode, using mongrel. So my suspicion is that some gem is doing needless work. How can I track this down? If this was some other sort of server rather than Rails, I would just profile the running server, but the Rails profiling solutions all seem to just profile the controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The well know [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) may help you. The config.ru file of your rails app will give you some hints on running the app manually.

For other alternatives take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350470/what-tools-do-you-recommend-to-profile-rails-apps) question.